# Using Regex with Python and replace over the whole file. Then Save the changes?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to run a regex replace on the contents of a file.

It is for a webserver. Normally it works fine but I found that the reason I am having issues with it is that the file is being split into lines of so many characters. Because of this its splitting the string and a line parse is no good.

How would I load the whole file and run the regex search on that data and replace it then write it back?

Below is the current code:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
regex = r"(<img.*src=3D.*)(http:\/\/.*>)"
new_file = []

import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='ProxyLog.log', level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')


with open(filename, 'r') as f:
   # Read the file contents and generate a list with each line
   lines = f.readlines()


logging.info('Handled: %s', filename)
subst = "\\1https://example.com/proxy.php?url=3D\\2"


# Iterate each line
for line in lines:
    match = re.search(regex, line)
    if match:
        # Make sure to add \n to display correctly when we write it back
        new_line =  re.sub(regex, subst, line, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
        #print(new_line)
        new_file.append(new_line)
    else:
        new_file.append(line)

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
     # go to start of file
     f.seek(0)
     # actually write the lines
     f.writelines(new_file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your regex is fine, you can read in the file into a single variable with `.read()`, and use something like this:

```py
import re
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
regex = r"(<img.*src=3D.*)(http://.*>)"

import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='ProxyLog.log', level=logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
   # Read the file contents into a single variable
   contents = f.read()

logging.info('Handled: %s', filename)
subst = r"\1https://example.com/proxy.php?url=3D\2"

# Replace the whole contents
new_contents = re.sub(regex, subst, contents, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
     # actually write the lines
     f.write(new_contents)
```

Note your pattern has no `^` nor `$`, so you do not need `re.MULTILINE` flag.

If you use a raw string literal, you can use single backslashes, `r"\1"` = `"\\1"`.

Comment: This worked great. I found an issue I will have to correct but wondered if ya had an idea? The regex works but I had to make a change to include newline. Now I found that the file contents have = characters at the end of the line. Which is splitting an HTTP statement so its not caught. How would I get a set amount of lines from the contents variable so I can just remove the last character in the line and not worry?

Comment: @TULOA Please provide a sample text with expected regex matches.